# Which gods does Indra rule over?

Tags: indra

Everywhere I look online, I see the same descriptions of Indra. He's described as the immortal king of the gods who resides in Amaravati, rides Airavata, and wields Vajra.

But which specific gods does Indra actually rule over? Do goddesses "report" to him too? Similarly, what is Indra's place in the pecking order relative to the Trimurthi?

Comment: Please read Shastras instead of online commentary. Indra has been praised in Ramayana Mahabharata and other texts as king of Gods (all Gods report to him). He's the most powerful God and responsible for killing most of asuras. Only the few worst ones are killed by Gods like Shiva and Vishnu. Yes he's been criticized for some action also. But that's minuscule of his resume.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Vishnu - Brahma - Shiva - Indra - (Agni,Vayu,Varuna etc.). The Trimurti are above him. Every Manvantara (14 chaturyugas), Indra changes. Next Indra is Mahabali.

Comment: Yes the trimurti and their families are above him. Also the avatars are above him.

Comment: Adityas, Vasus, Rudras, Ashwinis, Gandharvas, Marudganas, Navagrahas, Apsaras and all other Devas excluding Trimurthi and Tridevis and their incarnations...